# port Ubuntu Touch to unsupported Tablet

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-touch, android, tablet, porting

I consider buying a Chinese tablet with an Exynos 5250 SoC. It is a Voyo A15. It is not supported by CyanogenMod, but there is a [Custom ROM](http://inspirationvoyoa15.blogspot.nl/) available for this tablet. I would want to install Ubuntu Touch on it.

My question: Would it be possible to port Ubuntu Touch to this device? Considering it has the same SoC as the Nexus 10. I have enough Linux experience (of building kernels etc.), so I could do (at least try to do) the porting myself. The manufacturer has not yet released the source for their ROM, but the drivers for the Exynos chip are available. The Exynos is not the only chip on the tablet, so if the manufacturer doesn't release those drivers, is it still possible?

Maybe this is not the right place to ask this question, should I try at CyanogenMod forums? Maybe there is someone with experience of porting CyanogenMod/UbuntuTouch to exotic Android Tablets?

Answer (score 1):

As of now it looks impossible to build without CM10.1

Ubuntu touch uses following parts from android,

- Linux Kernel (stock Android kernel provided by the vendor, with a few changes to support some extra features needed by Ubuntu)
- OpenGL ES2.0 HAL and drivers
- Audio/Media HAL and services, to re-use the hardware video decoders
- RILD for modem support

If you get hold of these then you can start working on it. [Here is the complete guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting)

Later point of time, it will be possible to [run ubuntu without android](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/FAQ#Can_you_make_it_run_on_my_device_xyz_as_well.3F). It may get easy (or difficult) for your device later.

Comment: Thanks (oh, saying "thanks" is to be avoided). So if I want Ubuntu Touch, CM10.1 is the first step. The Exynos 5250 is not the problem as it is supported by Ubuntu Touch. Would there be other problems, such as a different screen, other brightness control, wifi, bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't need to be in CyanogenMod. You need Android 4.1 and above (jellybean) and ClockworkMod. Hope that helps. CyanogenMod 10 is also 4.1+. Anyway what version is your Android.

Comment: Currently it's 4.2.2. However, someone on a Spanish forum did a great job porting cyanogenmod to this device http://www.htcmania.com/showthread.php?t=679225 and he is about to release the cyanogen build tree. But for Ubuntu Touch we need to recompile the kernel. (?)